# Is NUnit 3 removing the 'classic' syntax for tests?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

Nunit currently has [two styles of writing test](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertions&r=2.6.3).

Classic style

```
Assert.AreEqual(x, y);
```

New Style

```
Assert.That(y, Is.EqualTo(x);
```

The Release notes for [NUnit 2.9.3](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=3.0) (Scroll down!) says

> Support for old style tests has been removed

Do they mean the Classic style is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not removed in v3. Looking at the latest alpha 2 we can see that the methods `Are*` still exist in the `Assert` object eg

```
public static void AreEqual(int expected, int actual)
{
    Assert.That<int>(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected), null, null);
}
```

Old style tests is the [prefixing of tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=upgrade&r=2.4) with "Test" (see also this [launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+spec/remove-old-style-tests))